# Solving foobar in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, math, testing, functional-programming, division

So far I have been able to get the numbers to print properly but I don't know how to loop them.

```
puts "Please enter a number"
val1 = gets.to_i
val2 = val1 % 3
val3 = val1 % 5


def ordinal(a,b,c)
    if b == 0 && c == 0
        return "foobar"
    elsif    b == 0
        return "foo"
    elsif c == 0
       return "bar"
    else
        return a
    end
end

val5 = ordinal(val1,val2,val3)
puts "#{val5}"
```

I also made a loop that works but it won't recognize strings.

```
n = 0
x = gets.to_i
while n != x
  puts "#{n}"
  n = n + 1
end
```

How do I combine my method and loop? Or is there any other way to solve this? But I would prefer if you solve it using my code IF its any good off course so that I can understand it better.

Comment: I have been able to get the answer correctly like this but it is incomplete until I can fit it into a loop so that the number of digits a user enters are all printed accordingly:

puts "Please enter a number"
val1 = gets.to_i
val2 = val1 % 3
val3 = val1 % 5


def ordinal(a,b,c)
    if b == 0 && c == 0
        return "foobar"
    elsif    b == 0
        return "foo"
    elsif c == 0
       return "bar"
    else
        return a
    end
end

val5 = ordinal(val1,val2,val3)
puts "#{val5}"

Comment: What does your code look like? We won't do your homework for you.

Comment: puts "Please enter a number"
val1 = gets.to_i
val2 = val1 % 3
val3 = val1 % 5


def ordinal(a,b,c)
    if b == 0 && c == 0
        return "foobar"
    elsif    b == 0
        return "foo"
    elsif c == 0
       return "bar"
    else
        return a
    end
end

val5 = ordinal(val1,val2,val3)
puts "#{val5}"

Comment: So you want us to do your homework for you? that's not nice. We're a community, not a crowd outsourcing site... having said that, look into [`Integer#times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-times), this could be useful for a solution where `def foo_bar(n); n.times {|i| out = i.to_s; out = "Something" if condition; ... print " #{out}" }; end;`

Comment: I didn't ask you to do my homework,I posted the code in my comments,read it please! Thanks

Comment: @stupidgeek aight, then you're fine. Though, please post your code in a edit to your original post.

Comment: Tips for asking good questions: add your code in the first edit, don't ask for complete solutions, don't beg (PLZ help me) either in the question or the comments, and refrain from txtspk if you can. Broadly here on Stack Overflow, the assistance people will offer is proportional to the effort they see in the question.

Comment: @halfer Thank you for the kind suggestions and editing my question also. This is my first attempt at using a website like this because i'm a newbie programmer with no experience. I'll learn to adapt to both programming and using this website appropriately to ask questions in a professionally acceptable manner. Thanks

Comment: All good @stupidgeek, welcome to Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As par your comments, the loop part is easy when leveraging [`Integer#times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-times).

This is what you have that works for you:

```
puts "Please enter a number"
val1 = gets.to_i
val2 = val1 % 3
val3 = val1 % 5
def ordinal(a,b,c)
    if b == 0 && c == 0
      return "footer"
    elsif b == 0
      return "foo"
    elsif c == 0
      return "bar"
    else
      return a
    end
end
val5 = ordinal(val1,val2,val3)
puts "#{val5}"
```

Right now you're just running through the final number. Try using the [`Integer#times`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Integer.html#method-i-times) to run a loop up to the number...:

```
puts "Please enter a number"
num = gets.to_i
num.times do |a|
    a += 1 # counting is done from 0 to n-1
    b = a % 3
    c = a % 5
    if b == 0 && c == 0
      print "foobar "
    elsif b == 0
      print "foo "
    elsif c == 0
      print "bar "
    else
      print "#{a} "
    end
end
print "\n"
```

Personally I would probably have written this a bit differently, but I guess it's sound enough.

I would probably write something messy because I hate long if...else statements...:

```
def foo_bar n
   n.times {|i| i+=1; print( (i%15==0 && "FooBar ") || (i%3==0 && "Foo ") || (i%5 ==0 && "Bar ") || ("#{i} ") ) }
   print "\n"
end
puts "Enter number:"
foo_bar gets.to_i
```

Comment: thank you so much for your response. I used the first code of block you responded with and it worked nicely. However I just wanted to know,how come when we use "puts" and "return",the code doesn't work? Isn't there little difference between them? Mainly that print does not create an extra line at the bottom like puts does and that return doesn't display anything to the screen at all so shouldn't it work in the loop/method we used? But it doesn't work. A little confused about this.

Comment: Using `puts` would add extra new lines in the code. However, the use of `return` actually exits the method and the loop, setting the method's response. You can lean more about the `return` keyword at [RubyMonk's](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/1-ruby-primer/chapters/19-ruby-methods/lessons/57-being-methodical) wonderful learning site.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this too:

```
def foobar n
   n.times do |i|
      i += 1
      num = ""
      num << "Foo" if i % 3 == 0
      num << "Bar" if i % 5 == 0
      num = i.to_s if num == ""
      puts num
   end
end
foobar 15
```

The logic is simpler than Myst's.
You don't need to test if it's a factor of 15.
Output:

```
1  
2  
Foo  
4  
Bar  
Foo  
7  
8  
Foo  
Bar  
11  
Foo  
13  
14  
FooBar  
=> 15
```

Comment: It an creative use of the String, although I don't see how the logic is any simpler. You still have three `if` statements, only one is checking the string instead of the number...

Comment: Well, what if it has to be divisible by 2, 7, and 9 also? Yours have to manually check for division by 6, 10, 14, 15, 18, and so on. The division by 15 showing "FooBar" clearly indicates that if a number is divisible by 2 different numbers then it should show both the strings shown for when it is divisible by each number. My concept of adding strings together for each condition met surely simplified the algorithm and make it run much faster if there are more conditions to meet because of less conditions to check.

Comment: you're outdoing yourself... but you're right. any more conditions and I would implement a dictionary. `def foo_bar(n) ;dic = [[3, "Foo"], [5,"Bar"], [15, "FooBar"], [9, "^Foo"] ]; n.times {|i| i+=1; s = i.to_s; dic.each {|j| s = j[1] if i%j[0] == 0}; print "#{s} " }; print "\n"; end`

Comment: Wow..why are you implementing your own dictionary? You know that array of arrays are slow, right? You can just use a hash of integer keys with strings as the values.